# Google Sheets Script lookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, editor, conditional-statements, vlookup

I'm trying to make a script in google sheets that make this:

I have a database with "id" and "product" in the sheet named "base":

[image: Database]

In another sheet I have the "id2" and the "product2":

[image: Search]

I need to create a Script that search (vlookup I think) the "id2" in the first database and bring 'yes' or 'no' according to the product2   and put it on the obs column

Comment: I don't think you really mean a "script", but rather a formula. A script would not have "vlookup" in it.

Answer (score 0):

This logic can be expressed by double application of `filter`: first, filter the columns of Sheet1 so that the column you get is the one with product name in it (B2 in your example); then filter the rows so you get the Id as in the cell A2.

```
=filter(filter(Sheet1!A2:D, Sheet1!A1:D1 = B2), Sheet1!A2:A = A2)
```